# this.setState makes variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to increment my state variable, but whenever I do so an error pops up which says that the variable state is undefined. **I defined my variable inside the constructor**. Obviously something is going on in the setState function.

Here is the code which renders an error:

```
displayDiv(){
  var arr=[];
  if (this.state.flag[2]){
    this.setState({counter:counter+4}); // error:undefined
    for (let i = this.state.counter-4; i < this.state.counter; i++)
      arr.push(this.state.arrayHeader[0].content);
    }
  }
 return(
   arr.map(function(item,i){
     return (
       <div className="bodydiv col-sm-3">
         <Header/>
         <Content/>
         <Tags/>
       </div>
     );

    })
  );
}
```

Here is the defined variable inside the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    arrayHeader:[],
    arraytag1:[],
    arraytag2:[],
    counter:0,
    flag:[false,false,false]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should change your code like this `this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 4});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to the other good answers:

**In short, you probably want something like this to be safe:**

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState, counter: prevState.counter+4
}));
```

---

Yes, your current problem was due to the undefined local variable `counter`  in this statement:

```
this.setState({ counter: counter+4 });
```

---

A simple solution (as pointed out by other answers already) is to refer to the respective state variable:

```
this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+4});
```

---

As pointed out by `cdaiga`, you'd probably want to preserve the other properties on your state since `setState()` is replacing the current state with the parameter provided to it and you'd effectively loose all other values on it. You could do it like this:

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, counter: this.state.counter+4 });
```

---

As per the [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), you should also take the asynchronous nature of `setState()` into account.

> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> For example, this code may fail to update the counter:
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> this.setState({
>     counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
> });
> ```
>
> To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
>     counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
> }));
> ```
>
> We used an arrow function above, but it also works with regular functions

---

In your specific example, we would end up with something like this (as already stated at the top):

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState, counter: prevState.counter+4
}));
```

---

Additional side note: due to this asynchronous nature of `this.setState()`, accessing `this.state` after calling `this.setState()` will still return its old value. Your original posted code is accessing `this.state.counter` immediately afterwards:

```
this.setState({counter:counter+4}); // error:undefined
for (let i = this.state.counter-4; i < this.state.counter; i++)
    arr.push(this.state.arrayHeader[0].content);
}
```

Fortunately in this case you're not using the variable `i` inside the loop and the `this.state.arrayheader[0].content` is not being updated, i.e. the following would be equivalent:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState, counter: prevState.counter+4
}));
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     arr.push(this.state.arrayHeader[0].content);
}
```

Comment: Could you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153957/value-becomes-undefined-because-of-setstate/67154970#67154970

Answer (score 9):

Your `counter +4` points nowhere.

It should be `this.state.counter + 4`

Also, if you are calling this function on the `render()` make sure it has been previously binded, you can do that like this on the constructor:

```
this.displayDiv = this.displayDiv.bind(this);
```

Comment: @eugen_sunic That's because `setState` updates their own stored values, so the full reference `this.state` is not needed. However, since you are not changing that value for something like `1` or `foo` but rather a value stored elsewhere, you need to pass it the full reference to that value (in this case `this.state.counter`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153957/value-becomes-undefined-because-of-setstate/67154970#67154970 Could you have a look here?

Answer (score 3):

I think its simple, try this in function `displayDiv`

```
this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+4});
```

you forgot the this.state at this line :)

Comment: Could you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153957/value-becomes-undefined-because-of-setstate/67154970#67154970

Answer (score 1):

You can replace:

```
this.setState({counter:counter+4}); // error:undefined
```

with:

```
const { counter } = this.state; // getting the counter from state
this.setState({counter:counter+4});
```

But then hope you really want to flush out all the other attributes of the state. Else you should do:

```
const { counter } = this.state;
this.setState(Object.assign({},this.state,{counter: counter + 4}));
```

See [how to use Object.assign() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Providing the unchanged parts of the state on `setState()` is not necessary, is it? And even if so, `this.setState({...this.state,counter: this.state.counter+4})` would also do the trick I imagine. No need for `Object.assign()` in any case.

Comment: Providing the unchanged part is necessary if we want to conserve it. If we don't provide it, it will be wiped of and the new state object will be the one passed to the `this.setState()` method. I agree with `this.setState({...this.state,counter: this.state.counter+4})` it does the same job as the one I already wrote. It's just creating a new object with the previous key-values of the state object then overriding the value of  counter attribute with the new one (`this.state.counter+4`).

Comment: As per the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) (where they use a similar example with a counter), you'd also have to take the asynchronous nature of `setState()` into account and rather provide a function as argument if you want to include one of its current values. I.e. `this.setState((oldState) => { return { ...oldState, counter: oldState.counter + 4 }; })`

Comment: Ok I now see, thank you for the clarification @Carsten.

Comment: Could you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153957/value-becomes-undefined-because-of-setstate/67154970#67154970