# value becomes undefined because of setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, p5.js, ml5.js

I am using p5 and ml5.js to train an ML model by adding some images via my webcam. The train function works fine like this. However, if I uncomment the if statement within the train function:

```
if (lossValue == null)
```

the value of `classifier` because `undefined` after that and it would throw an error in the next step. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?
If I just use a console.log inside the if statement, it doesn't create a problem. However, if I use the setState inside it, it sets the classifier to undefined.

```
export const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    const [prediction, setPrediction] = useState<string>();
    const [confidence, setConfidence] = useState<string>();
    const [trainingComplete, setTrainingComplete] = useState<boolean>();
    //const [lossValue, setLoss] = useState<any>();

    let capture: p5Types.Element;
    let classifier: any;
    const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {
        capture = p5.createCapture(p5.VIDEO).parent(canvasParentRef);
        const featureExtractor = ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady);
         classifier = featureExtractor.classification(capture, videoReady);
    }

    const draw = (p5: p5Types) => {
    }

    function modelReady() {
        console.log('Model Ready');
    }

    function videoReady() {
        console.log('Video Ready');
    }


    function gotResult() {
        console.log('classifier in results', classifier);
        classifier.classify(capture, (err: any, result: any) => {
            setPrediction(result[0].label);
            
        });
    }

    function train() {
        console.log('classifier in train', classifier);
        classifier.train((lossValue: any) => {
            console.log('Loss is', lossValue);
            // if (lossValue == null){
            //  setTrainingComplete(true);
            // }
        });
        console.log('classifier in train', classifier);
    }



    return (<div><Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} className="sketch" />
        <div className="button">
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {classifier.addImage('first');console.log('image added')}}>First</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {classifier.addImage('second');console.log('image added')}}>Second</Button>
        </div>
        <div className="secondbutton">
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => train()}>Train!</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => gotResult()}>Test!</Button>
            <br />
            {trainingComplete && (<span>Training Complete!</span>)}<br />
        </div>
    </div>)
        ;
};
```

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-solomon-zb34l?file=/src/Component.tsx

Comment: Maybe the called method `setTrainingComplete(true)` sets classifier to undefined?!

Comment: Yup, that's what's causing the issue, as mentioned in the qs @Lynx242

Comment: Are you and @x89 working together?  I just answered another question about this same code.  Different problem, same core issue.  You need to use `useRef`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67116772/typeerror-cannot-read-property-classify-of-undefined-save-ml5-js-model/67154884#67154884

Comment: The solution in the answer below does not work. Could someone else try in the codesandboy?

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `classifier` as a `let` variable.  It is not a state so it does not persist across re-renders.  Every time your component gets re-rendered the code `let classifier: any;` gets executed and `classifier` becomes `undefined`.

When you call a `setState` function such as `setTrainingComplete(true)` this changes the state of your component and causes it to re-render.  Therefore you lose the value of `classifier`.

You want to keep the value of `classifier` so you need to store it using a [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) or [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook.  I generally use `useRef` when dealing with complex objects from external libraries which have their own internal state.  So that's what I suggest here.

```
const classifierRef = useRef<any>();
```

```
function train() {
    const classifier = classifierRef.current;
    console.log('classifier in train', classifier);
    classifier?.train((lossValue: any) => {
        console.log('Loss is', lossValue);
        if (lossValue == null) {
            setTrainingComplete(true);
        }
    });
    console.log('classifier in train', classifier);
}
```

Comment: it only worked after I added useRef for the capture too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **useRef** for the **capture** variable as well. https://dementorwriter.medium.com/picture-classification-with-react-ml5-c45672aeb961